# Comparing Dates in a MYSQL Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

```
 class
 -------------
 id    name
 -------------
 1     Knives
 2     Pastries


 class_date
 -------------
 get_id    start_date
 -------------
 1         2017-10-09
 1         2017-11-15
 1         2017-12-03
 2         2017-10-30
```

The class 'Knives' is a series with multiple dates. The class 'Pastries' is only offered on one date.

I want my result to be based on Oct 10, 2017 (or current date). In my search I only want results based on the first date - in this case the date of Oct 9, 2017 for 'Knives' should disqualify it from showing up in the results. 'Pastries' should show up.

I am not sure if I should do a LEFT OUTER JOIN or a Subquery. I've tried both but neither works - but I'm probably not doing it correctly.

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT *  
FROM class, class_date WHERE
class_date.get_id = class.id &&
(SELECT DATE(start_date)
FROM class, class_date WHERE 
class_date.get_id = classes.id 
ORDER BY class_date.start_date ASC
LIMIT 1
) > CURDATE() 
ORDER BY class_date.start_date ASC
```

and

```
SELECT *  
FROM class
LEFT OUTER JOIN
class_date ON
class_date.get_id = classes.id 
WHERE
class_date.start_date > CURDATE() 
GROUP BY classes.class_id
ORDER BY class_dates.start_date ASC
```

I have a feeling that the subquery is the way to go but I get no results. If I use < instead of > I get too many results. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think your description confuses knives and pastries.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method to get the most recent record as of a particular date.  This allows you to get all the rows (and you can join in `class` to get rows there):

```
select cd.*
from class_date cd
where cd.date = (select max(cd2.date)  
                 from class_date cd2
                 where cd2.get_id = cd.get_id and
                       cd2.date <= '2017-10-09'
                );
```

If you just want the maximum date for a given class:

```
select cd.get_id, max(cd.date)  
from class_date cd
where cd.date <= '2017-10-09'
group by cd.get_id;
```

Comment: Thanks - I guess I could get the relevant dates and then loop through the results to get the class info. I was thinking of a more elegant solution though.